# One user is unable to open in explorer/view in datasheet

Tags: 2007, datasheet, explorer

One member of my team has lost the ability to open in explorer view and view in datasheet. Just randomly, and we cannot work out why.

All settings are matching of his machine is matching with mine. There is no rhyme or reason to it.

We are all using IE8 x32 and Sharepoint 2003.

I've checked permissions and everything fine there.

Comment: You have tagged the question with 2007, but state you use SharePoint 2003, which on is it?

Comment: Is user is getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below points:

1. Request that user to login into SharePoint from your machine. If
   everything works on your machine with his login then its not a
   permission issue or any other issue from SharePoint end.
2. Add the SharePoint site in trusted site zone at users machine, check whether this resolves the issue
3. This might be some active-x component missing issue.